Нужно API для проверки валидности паспорта РФ
Компания заказчика по закону должен проверять валидность паспорта гражданина РФ. Пытаемся найти решение, но пока без результата.
Есть API по базе МВД, но она актуальна только до 23 года.
По API Госуслуг непонятно даёт ли она возможность проверять валидность.
